# how to include catkin package?

Tags: ros, catkin, build-package, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

suppose i have directory tree like this :

```
.
├── .catkin_tools
│   ├── CATKIN_IGNORE
│   ├── profiles
│   │   └── default
│   ├── README
│   └── VERSION
└── src
    ├── pkg_a
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── mutiply.cpp
    │   ├── package.xml
    │   └── sumfunc.cpp
    └── pkg_b
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── main.cpp
        └── package.xml

6 directories, 10 files
```

how can i edit  **CMakeLists.txt** So that i can use those file in pkg_a inside pkg_b/main.cpp like  this :

```
#include <pkg_a/mutiply.cpp>
#include <pkg_a/sumfunc.cpp>
#include <pkg_a/someheader.h>// or maybe this one

int main(void) {
    int sum_result = sum(5,5);
    int muli_result = muti(5,5);
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE : i already take a look at this [recommend](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html) but i not quite understand it.

## Edit :

after @Weasfas Answer i have create func_terminal.h file in pkg_a and have this tree file :

```
└── src
    ├── pkg_a
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── func_terminal.h
    │   ├── mutiply.cpp
    │   ├── package.xml
    │   └── sumfunc.cpp
    └── pkg_b
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── main.cpp
        └── package.xml
```

and add some command in cmakeList.txt in pkg_b : add find package

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp pkg_a)
```

add include_directories

```
include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}

)
```

add catkin package

```
catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS pkg_a
)
```

and in building

```
add_executable(main_node main.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(main_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES}) 
add_dependencies(main_node ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

then edit package.xml by add these line

```
  <build_depend>pkg_a</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>pkg_a</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>pkg_a</exec_depend>
```

but i will get an error

```
fatal error: pkg_a/func_terminal.h: No such file or directory
```

from catkin build if i try to add this line `#include <pkg_a/func_terminal.h>` in pkg_b/main.cpp file

## Edit #2(RECAP):

I'll explain the solution i have got thank to @Weasfas steb by steb here :
first i need to create a proper catkin_work_space for example in my case i use these command :

```
mkdir tryCatkin && mkdir tryCatkin/src && cd tryCatkin && catkin_make
```

then i can either use `catkin_create_pkg` command or just create out of of nowhere by following catkin package format which will create directory tree like this:

```
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
│   ├── pkg_a
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── include
│   │   │   └── pkg_a
│   │   │       └── fuction_terminal.hpp
│   │   ├── package.xml
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── function_terminal.cpp
│   └── pkg_b
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── include
│       │   └── pkg_b
│       ├── package.xml
│       └── src
│           └── main.cpp
```

in pkg_b/src/main.cpp  :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pkg_a/fuction_terminal.hpp>

int main(void) {
    int sum_result = sumation(5,5); ///sumation is function in func_terminal.hpp
    std::cout << "test :  " << sum_result;

    return 0;
}
```

then setup those package.xml and CmakeList.txt which i follow from @Weasfas instruction. first in pkg_a/Cmakelist.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pkg_a)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES SumFunc
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(SumFunc
   src/function_terminal.cpp
)
```

pkg_b/CmakeList.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pkg_b)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  pkg_a
)
catkin_package()

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(main_node src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main_node
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

and then in pkg_b/package.xml add this line:

```
  <depend>pkg_a</depend>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357920/how-to-include-catkin-package-?/) by [Cry-A-Lot](https://answers.ros.org/users/56597/cry-a-lot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Cry-A-Lot,

The recommended link you posted explains you how to compile a target against a library of the same package.

The first recommendation is that you should not include `cpp` files in your code but `hpp` or or `h` (header) since with that intruction (E.g.: `#include <pkg_a/mutiply.cpp>`) the compiler will probably throw an error because of the multiples and function duplications.

After you have generated properly your headers you should compile your targets against your libraries. It means that, if for instance you have in `sumfunc.cpp` something you want to use in `main.cpp` you should compile your `main.cpp` as:

EDIT:

I have managed to achieve what you want, first of all the package structure is the following:

```
└── src
    ├── pkg_a
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── include
    │   │  ├── package_a
    │   │  │   ├── some_func.hpp
    │   ├── src
    │   │  ├── some_func.cpp
    │   └── package.xml
    └── pkg_b
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── src
    │   │   ├── main.cpp
    │   └── package.xml
```

Then in CmakeList.txt of `package_a`:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  ...
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES SumFunc
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(SumFunc
   src/sum_func.cpp
)
```

And to use in `package_b`:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  package_a
  ...
)

catkin_package()

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(main_node src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main_node
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Hope that solve your problem.

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cry-A-Lot](https://answers.ros.org/users/56597/cry-a-lot/) on 2020-07-29**:
i try to edit like you said but i still got an error: "fatal error: pkg_a/func_terminal.h: No such file or directory" what am i miss

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-07-29**:
Mmm how is your package structure? Maybe you forgot a dependency.

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-07-31**:
So I have edited my answers to a achievable solution to see if that can help you.

**Comment by [Cry-A-Lot](https://answers.ros.org/users/56597/cry-a-lot/) on 2020-08-03**:
i have follow instruction from you EDIT section , but i still doesn't work with me and got an error : "Could not find a package configuration file provided by "package_a" " could you please re-check it.

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-08-03**:
@Cry-A-Lot , that is a usual problem when the CMakeList.txt of one package is bad implemented. How is your cmake. That message is telling you that catkin is unable to find the `package_a` in the workspace so, either you defined bad your CMakeList.txt or you package.xml is not well formed.

**Comment by [Cry-A-Lot](https://answers.ros.org/users/56597/cry-a-lot/) on 2020-08-04**:
it only occur when i add package_a inside

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  # package_a)
```

this is  my pgk_a/CmakeList.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(pkg_a)
  
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES SumFunc
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(SumFunc
   src/func_terminal.cpp
)
```

this is my pkg_b/CmakeList.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(pkg_b)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  # package_a
)

catkin_package()

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(main_node src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main_node
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-08-04**:
Well the package name you gave is not `package_a` but `pkg_a`. That may be the problem of catkin not finding it.

**Comment by [Cry-A-Lot](https://answers.ros.org/users/56597/cry-a-lot/) on 2020-08-04**:
if i replace `package_a` with `pkg_a` it still give an error : `Project 'pkg_a' specifies 'include' as an include dir, which is not found.`

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-08-04**:
Then you have problems with the workspace not with the packages themselves. It looks like `catkin` is unable to find the package `pkg_a` so either you configured bad your workspace or your enviromental variables are not properly set. Did you [source](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) the workspace?

**Comment by [Cry-A-Lot](https://answers.ros.org/users/56597/cry-a-lot/) on 2020-08-05**:
it work now, THANK!!!